# SSRS Stop line from moving to next page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, page-break

I have a report that displays line items and then the total of all the items. When there is 5 items they go on the first page and the a second page is created for only the total line. 
Is there a way to say if there is 5 place four on the first page and the fifth and the total on the second page? 
It is just weird having a page that just says this total and no line items.
My ms-sql server is 2008 R2.

Comment: You could experiment with expressions for the tablix-height property.

Comment: Any chance we can get a picture?